# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k{\binom{2m}{k}}^3=(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}\binom{3m}{m}$ (Dixon's identity)

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I found the following formula in a book without any proof:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k{\binom{2m}{k}}^3=(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}\binom{3m}{m}.$$

I don't know how to prove this at all. Could you show me how to prove this? Or If you have any helpful information, please teach me. I need your help.

*Update* : I [crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143334/proving-sum-k-02m-1k-binom2mk3-1m-binom2mm-binom3mm).

Comment: For simpler equations of this form, the trick would be to let $S_{2m} = \sum^{2m}_{k=0}(-1)^k\binom{2m}{k}^3$ and try to solve the equation $S_{2(m+1)} - S_{2m} = ...$.

If this doesn't work, perhaps try induction? $m = 0$ is straightforward to check. However the induction bit will certainly hardcore.

Comment: @user88595: Thanks, but I suspect that your idea doesn't work.

Comment: @user88595, concerning the answer below; I think the choice of the polynomials are wrong. However if you look at the coefficient of ${xy}^{2m}$ in $$
(1-x)^{2m}(1+xy)^{2m}(1+y)^{2m}
$$ then you get the left hand term. To get the right hand side I was working for a while but no clue for the moment.

Comment: Related: [Combinatorial Proof of Dixon's Identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338682/a-combinatorial-proof-of-dixons-identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Igor Rivin on MO.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143334/proving-sum-k-02m-1k-binom2mk3-1m-binom2mm-binom3mm

Mark Wildon mentioned that this is Dixon's identity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity

Answer (score 5):

#### Good$^\dagger$ proof

**0.** Let's prove more general form of Dixon's identity:
$$
\sum(-1)^k\binom{a+b}{b+k}\binom{b+c}{c+k}\binom{c+a}{a+k}=\binom{a+b+c}{a,b,c}
$$
(the version from OP corresponds to $a=b=c=n$).

**1.** Trinomial coefficients satisfy — and are defined by — a simple recurrence. So we only need to show that LHS — let's denote it $F(a,b,c)$ — satisfies
$$
F(a,b,c)=F(a-1,b,c)+F(a,b-1,c)+F(a,b,c-1).
$$

**2.** Let's rewrite LHS in 'Dyson style': it's the constant term of
$$
(-1)^{a+b+c}\frac{(x-y)^{a+b}(y-z)^{b+c}(z-x)^{c+a}}{x^{2a}y^{2b}z^{2c}}.
$$
But now the recurrence follows immediately from the identity
$$
\frac{y^2}{(x-y)(y-z)}+\frac{z^2}{(y-z)(z-x)}+\frac{x^2}{(z-x)(x-y)}=-1
$$
(which is [due to Euler](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502425), I believe).

---

$^\dagger$‘Good’ as in ‘I.J.Good. Short Proof of a Conjecture by Dyson’

Answer (score 4):

// I thought it would be nice to have an actual solution on this page (especially if that is not one of solutions posted @ MO).

OK, so we want to compute the coefficient
$$
[z^{2m}w^{2m}]\left\{(1-z)^{2m}(1-w)^{2m}(z-w)^{2m}\right\}
$$
i.e. the residue
$$
\operatorname*{res}_{z,w}\frac{(1-z)^{2m}(1-w)^{2m}(z-w)^{2m}}{z^{2m}w^{2m}}\frac{dz}z\frac{dw}w;
$$
after the substitution $Z=z/(1-w)$, $W=w/(1-z)$ (using that $z-w=\frac{Z-W}{1-ZW}$ and $\frac{dz}z\frac{dw}w=\frac{dZ\,dW}{ZW(1-ZW)}$) we see that it's equal to
$$
\operatorname*{res}_{Z,W}\frac{(Z-W)^{2m}}{(1-ZW)^{2m}Z^{2m}W^{2m}}\frac{dZ\,dW}{ZW(1-ZW)}=
[(ZW)^{2m}]\left\{\frac{(Z-W)^{2m}}{(1-ZW)^{2m+1}}\right\}
$$
which is equal to $(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}\binom{3m}m$.

// The substitution looks somewhat magical. I've learned it from Gessel–Stanton [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316585900263) mentioned by Todd Trimble @ MO.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a (full) answer, but it won't fit to a comment (and I hope it can be finished; but I also hope that there is a much simpler solution).
The LHS is the coefficient $C_{2n}$ at $1$ in $((1-z)(1-w)(1-(zw)^{-1}))^{2n}$.
We have 
$$C_n=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}\oint\oint((1-z)(1-w)(1-(zw)^{-1}))^{n}\frac{dz}{z}\frac{dw}{w}$$
(we integrate over the unit circles).
Let us compute $F(t):=\sum_n C_n t^n$. We just sum a geometric series and get

$$F(t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}\oint\oint\frac{1}{zw-t(1-z)(1-w)(zw-1)}dz\,dw.$$
Let's compute the integral wrt. $z$ using residues. In the denominator we have a quadratic polynomial in $z$ with one root in the unit disk, so the residue is $\sqrt{}$ of its discriminant, and we get (modulo calculation mistakes)
$$F(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{1}{\sqrt{(w+t(w^2-1))^2-4t^2w(1-w)^2}}dw.$$
Under the square root we have a quartic polynomial in $w$, hence $F(t)$ is a [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind). Now we need to bring it to the normal form, or compute its Taylor series directly; at least for now I lack the energy to do it.

Comment: Should that be $(1-z)(1-w)(1-(zw)^{-1})^{2n}$?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer you mean why $n$ and not $2n$? I'm just computing a bit more (i.e. $C_n$, not just $C_{2n}$), though in the end I didn't really compute anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: use Newton's binomial on both sides of $$(1-x)^{2n}(1+y)^{2n}(1+z)^{2n}=[(1-x)(1+y)(1+z)]^{2n}$$

then track down and equate the coefficients at terms of the form $(xyz)^k$ on both sides. This should yield the required sum.

Comment: The idea of using polynomials is fine however I doubt how to get the left side of the equality