# How to prove this indentity $\binom{100}{0}^2-\binom{100}{1}^2+\binom{100}{2}^2-...-\binom{100}{99}^2+\binom{100}{100}^2=\binom{100}{50}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I don't know how to prove this identity:
$\binom{100}{0}^2-\binom{100}{1}^2+\binom{100}{2}^2-\binom{100}{3}^2+...-\binom{100}{99}^2+\binom{100}{100}^2=\binom{100}{50}$

Comment: Are you sure that this identity even holds?

Comment: @5xum A simple PARI-GP script verifies that the above identity holds true.

Comment: Yes, I tried it myself. First I tried to replace $100$ with $2$ and id didn't hold, so I got a bit worried. I now agree.

Comment: Apparently this already has a detailed answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/664802/73025).