# Prove $\sum_k{{a+b \choose a+k}{b+c \choose b+k}{c+a \choose c+k}(-1)^k}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, multinomial-coefficients

How can I prove this: $$\sum_k{{a+b \choose a+k}{b+c \choose b+k}{c+a \choose c+k}(-1)^k}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$$

I know I should avoid no clue questions, but really I have no idea about this one. I tried opening combinations but didn't give me anything. Both combinatorial and algebraical proofs are welcomed. Any help or hint is so much appreciated!

*Note*: I want a more elementary way than using Laurent series method.

Comment: Hello there. Binomial coefficients scream for hypergeometric function of some sort. Don't know if that'll work, but nonetheless it is perhaps a way.

Comment: This is indeed related to Hypergeometric Identities (Although other combinatorial proofs may exist), refer $(2.6)$ [Hypergeometric Identities](https://www.mathematik.uni-kassel.de/~koepf/CA/Kapitel2.pdf)

Comment: There is an obvious conjecture for
the product of $m$ terms
with $(a_j)_{j=1}^m$
and $a_{m+1}$ meaning $a_1$:

$\sum_{k} \prod_{j=1}^m \binom{a_j+a_{j+1}}{a_j+k}(-1)^k
=\dfrac{(\sum_{j=1}^m a_j)!}{\prod_{j=1}^m a_j!}
$.
This is probably in Riordan or Knuth.

Comment: This is called Dixon's Identity, BTW.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338682/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119176/42969

Comment: I have now added a much more elementary proof at the link [How to show that $\sum_{k} (-1)^k{{a+b}\choose{a+k}}{{b+c}\choose{b+k}}{{c+a}\choose{c+k}} = \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119176/how-to-show-that-sum-k-1kab-chooseakbc-choosebkca-ch) and vote to close this as a duplicate. Note that asking for more simplicity than that proof won't be possible : it only uses Chu-Vandermonde (which is a simple counting argument) and factorial manipulation, which is tedious but routine.